# How can I add an int input with space in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, median, mode

I've trying to have an input as an integer with space between, for example
 `1 2 3 4 5` instead of `12345`. I need to have space between them so I can calculate and process median, mode, mean and standard deviation. Note that I've tried `Integer.parseInt()` before.

```java
import javax.sound.midi.SysexMessage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FinalProg {

        Button button;
        public static void main(String[] args) {


//        int[] dataSet = {1,2,3,4,345,312,756,0,-234321132,234};
//        int[] dataSet = {5,3,2,5,2,5,758,345,32,231,5,5,5,2,2};

//        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//        String input = scanner.nextLine();
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//        int [] dataSet = new int[input.length()];

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scanner.nextLine(); //Numbers inputted from user in your case
            String[] list;             //List to store individual numbers
            list = input.split(" ");     // Regex to split the String so you get each number

            //Mean
            int sum = 0;

            for (String n : list) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(n);
            }

            System.out.println("The mean of the data set is  " +
                    ((double) sum / list.length));


            //Median
            Arrays.sort(list);
            if (list.length  % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2]));
            } else {
                System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2] + list[list.length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0);
            }

            //Mode

            int maxNumber = -1;
            int maxAppearances = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                int count = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                    if (list[i] == list[j]) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (count > maxAppearances) {
                    maxNumber = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
                    maxAppearances = count;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("The mode of the data set: " + maxNumber);


        //STDV

        double STDVsum = 0.0, standardDeviation = 0.0;
        int length = list.length;
        for(String num : list) {
            STDVsum += Double.parseDouble( num);
        }
        double mean = STDVsum/length;
        for(String num: list) {
            standardDeviation += Double.parseDouble(Math.pow(num - mean, 2)); // It says operator - doesn't apply...
        }
        System.out.println( "STDV "+ Math.sqrt(standardDeviation/length));

        }


        }
}
```

I expect to have an input for example like `1 2 3 4 5` processed and calculated instead of taking `12345`. As you see above in the code, 
I have an array of integers but missing the input with space in this case

Edited: (new update)
The results show for the example is:

2 3 4 5 6 7 6 6
The mean of the data set is  4.875
The median of the data set is: 32.5
The mode of the data set: 2

But the correct result is:

Mean:   4.875
Median: 5.5
Mode:   6

In addition, I couldn't calculate STDV because I couldn't convert:
standardDeviation += Double.parseDouble(Math.pow(num - mean, 2));

Comment: You want you input to be individual numbers like 1 then 2 then 3 etc but inputted by the user on the same line ?

Comment: Yes, as the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this just ask the user for the numbers take them as a String split them with .split(" ") and then parse them as Integers to your sum.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine(); //Numbers inputted from user in your case 
    String[] list ;             //List to store individual numbers
    list = input.split(" ");     // Regex to split the String so you get each number                         
    int sum = 0;                //Your sum

    for(String i : list)        //Iterate through Array 
    {
         sum += Integer.parseInt(i); //Parse the string value as int to your sum
    }
    System.out.println(sum);  // to check if everything worked fine
```

On the other issues you faced: Median was wrong because here :

```
    System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2] + list[list.length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0);
```

You don't account for the list[list.length/2] value being a String. Hotfixed that issue like this:

```
    float median = (Integer.parseInt(list[list.length/2]Integer.parseInt(list[(list.length/2)-1])) / 2f ;
    System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + median);
```

Regarding Mode issue, you just forgot again that you are dealing with an array of Strings and checked if on is equal to the other in a wrong way:

```
    if (list[i] == list[j]) {
           count++;
    }
```

If you want to check if 2 String are equal you do it like this

```
    if (list[i].equals(list[j])) {
                count++;
            }
```

Also i think you need to reset count after you check each number so add this here too:

```
                if (count > maxAppearances) {
            maxNumber = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
            maxAppearances = count;
        }
        count=0;
    }
```

STDV issue num in this case is still a string so you cannot call Math.pow on it :

```
    standardDeviation += Double.parseDouble(Math.pow(num - mean, 2));
```

Fixed by parsing num to int

```
    for(String num: list) {
        int num_to_Integer = Integer.parseInt(num);
        standardDeviation += Math.pow(num_to_Integer - mean, 2); //No need to parse now
    }
```

Check if STDV now returns correct results.

Comment: I got it, but there is no input. The test has an example instead of input like Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String

Comment: It seems works but check the results above, there's a bug within it. And, I couldn't convert             standardDeviation += Double.parseDouble(Math.pow(num - mean, 2)); // because It says operator - doesn't apply...

Comment: Try casting num to Integer in another value first and then do as below:::
    int num_to_int = Integer.parseInt(num);
    Double.parseDouble(Math.pow(num_to_int - mean, 2));

Comment: Everything works fine as you in the results below                                             
 12 13 15 16 24 15 22 10 9 13 13 18 16 25 23 24
The mean of the data set is  16.75
The median of the data set is: 808.0 wrong
The mode of the data set: 13
STDV 5.11737237261468


3 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 6 5
The mean of the data set is  5.0
The median of the data set is: 27.5 wrong
The mode of the data set: 3
STDV 1.4142135623730951        except median is wrong!?

Comment: What the median should be in each case?

Comment: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/statistics/mean-median-mode.php

Comment: I can't find why it does this now mainly because i don't know how median is calculated so try seeing what values it gets and you will find the error. Hope i helped.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks! can you check and fix Mode? You see the input for example 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, the result  would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but in the program is just 1 https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/statistics/mean-median-mode.php

Comment: If i understand correctly if the set given is odd then Mode is all the numbers given correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input as a string then convert the string to an array of int values.

Like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = sc.nextLine();
    int[] numbers = new int[input.length()];

    int index = 0;
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()){
        numbers[index] = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        index++;
    }
```

You should be able to use the numbers array for your calculations.

Comment: This doesn't work because it also adds to the array numbers the value -1 for each space in the String inputted